# url rewrite with translation htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I've got a multilang website, with some links like `mysite.com/about.html`. For all languages I've got a translation for the words used in the menu.

I want my url to be dynamic for differents languages. Such as my link of about page for `de` will be `mysite.com/de/de-about-translation.html`. The `de-about-translation.html` content is saved in a file for the `de` language.

## for more clarification:

I've a menu for choosing languages in my site. here user can switch between languages. when any one want to switch into differents languages i want to change all of menu links into selected language.

i've a file for  menu translation  of each languages. for Svenska my file name is sv.php and my file contents like this:

```
   $_lang["about_tr"] = "about-translation-of-Svenska ";
   $_lang["archive_tr"] = " archive-translation-of-Svenska ";


 For Deutsch language file contents:


  $_lang["about_tr"] = "about-translation-of-Deutsch ";
  $_lang["archive_tr"] = " archive-translation-of-Deutsch ";
```

Currently, I've links like :

```
mysite.com/about.html                 
mysite.com/archive.html
```

I want those links for Deutsch language like:

```
mysite.com/de/about-translation-of-Deutsch.html
mysite.com/de/about-translation-of-Deutsch.html
```

for the Svenska language those links should be like this:

```
mysite.com/se/about-translation-of-Svenska.html
mysite.com/se/archive-translation-of-Svenska.html
```

and so on for each language.

```
What kind of `RewriteRule` should I use in htaccess ?
```

Comment: Difficult to understand your problem. Would you give some examples of required source and target URIs with this `.htaccess`.

Comment: Where do you get the language from or is it according to browser's settings?

Comment: Thanks all for quick responses. Now i've edit my question with more details.please take a look. thanks again ..

Comment: @AwladLiton   But still, it is not clear where should the rewrite rule redirect to. Is the language code in the incoming URL, for example? Has to be somewhere to be able to generate the substitution URL. For example, to go to `mysite.com/se/about...` how is the requested URL? If it is just `mysite.com/about.html`, the rule can't know it has to redirect to `/se/` and not to `/de/` or to `/en/`. The request should be something like `mysite.com/se/about.html` for this idea to work.

Comment: @faa, thanks. my actual url will be like this:         mysite.com/about.html?lang=de  and i want to redirect it to mysite.com/de/de-translation-of-about.html. i think it will be clear to you.

Comment: If the incoming URL is something like `mysite.com/de/de-translation-of-about.html` it should be silently mapped to `mysite.com/about.html?lang=de`, where `about` is the dynamic string before the period `.` and after the last dash `-`, and `de` is the dynamic string in the 1st level of the incoming URL directory structure. Is that right?

Comment: Yes you right. a little bit confusion here: the whole text 'de-translation-of-about' will be dynamic. this text will be replaced by the $_lang["about_tr"] .

Comment: @faa , My Browser url will be:   mysite.com/de/arkiv.html my actual url will be mysite.com/archive.html?lang=de.here archive will be replace by the arkiv.html

Comment: @Awlad Okay. But, the `html` extension is not needed. To achieve "pretty" URLs, remember that the incoming path does not have to exist. If, for example, it is just ` mysite.com/de/arkiv`, it holds enough information to map it silently to `mysite.com/arkiv.html?lang=de`. The URL that is displayed in the browser's address bar is always the first one. Maybe something like this would be better, unless you definitely want to show the extension and/or the resource (script) is always `archive`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27067/discussion-between-awlad-liton-and-faa)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Example: `http://mysite.com/de/arkiv` to
> `http://mysite.com/arkiv.html?lang=de`

You may try something like this in one .htaccess file at root directory.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}   !\.html             [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?  /$2.html?lang=$1 [L,NC]
```

Maps silently

`http://mysite.com/LangCode/filename` displayed in the browser's address bar

To:

`http://mysite.com/filename.html?lang=LangCode`

#### Option:

If you want to have a single script (LanguageScript, for example) to handle all languages, just replace this line:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?  /$2.html?lang=$1 [L,NC]
```

with this one:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?  /LanguageScript.html?lang=$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: @AwladLiton Take your time to test it. Hope it works for you. I have to go now, but will be checking this answer in case you need any additional info or modification.

Comment: Hi Faa, thanks for your reply. now i've got this error:            The requested URL /se/archive.html was not found on this server.

Comment: Thanks Faa .. it works just i needed few changes:        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d                      RewriteRule ^([a-z][a-z])/([a-z]+.html)/?$  $2?lang=$1 [NC,L]    this works for me ...

Comment: That's because you are adding the extension (html) in the request. If you don't use it, there is no need for modifications. If you have to include it, let me know and I will modify my code. The way you did it limits the incoming strings to letters and for any request containing symbols or digits, the rule wont be applied.

Comment: Thanks again @faa, so its done for me.i have pages(about.html,archive.html).can you please give example for dynamic string for about.html or archive.html.